# Is there a better way to write this firebase cloud function than what I have right now?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have been trying to learn firebase cloud functions recently and I have wrote an http that takes the itemName, sellerUid, and quantity. Then I have a background trigger (an onWrite) that finds the Item Price with the provided sellerUid and itemName and computes the total (Item Price * Quantity) and then writes it into a document in firestore.

**My question is:**

with what I have right now, suppose my client purchases N items, this means that I will have:

- N reads (from the N items' price searching),
- 2 writes (one initial  write for the *N items* and 1 for the *Total Amount* after computation),
- ***N number of searches from cloud function??***

I am not exactly sure how cloud functions count towards read and writes as well as the amount of compute time it needs (though it's all just text though so should be negligible?)

Would love to hear your thoughts on if what I have is already good enough or is there a much more efficient way of going about this.

Thanks!

```
exports.itemAdded = functions.firestore.document('CurrentOrders/{documentId}').onWrite(async (change, context) => {
    const snapshot = change.after.data();
    var total = 0;
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(snapshot)) {
        if (value['Item Name'] != undefined) {
            await admin.firestore().collection('Items')
                       .doc(key).get().then((dataValue) => {
                const itemData = dataValue.data();
                if (!dataValue.exists) {
                    console.log('This is empty');
                } else {
                    total += (parseFloat(value['Item Quantity']) * parseFloat(itemData[value['Item Name']]['Item Price']));
                }
            });
            console.log('This is in total: ', total);
        }
    }
    snapshot['Total'] = total;
    console.log('This is snapshot afterwards: ', snapshot);
    return change.after.ref.set(snapshot);
});
```

Comment: If you want feedback on code you've written, that belongs on Code Review Stack Exchange: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

With your current approach you will be billed with:

- N reads (from the N items' price searching);
- 1 write that triggers your `onWrite` function;
- 1 write that persists the total value;

One better approach that I can think of is one of comparing the size of the list of values in `change.before.data()` and `change.after.data()`, and reading the current total value (0 if this is the first time) and afterwards add only the values that were added in `change.after.data()` instead of N values, which would potentially result in you being charged for less reads.

For the actual pricing, if you check this [Documentation for Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing), you will see that on your case only invocation and compute billing applies to your case, however there is a free tier for both, so if you are using this only to learn and this app does not have a lot of use, you should be on the free tier with either approach.

Let me know if you need any more information.